# more than 16 colours on graphics.h in C++ in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: c++, bitmap, ubuntu-12.04, bgi, bpp

I was just wondering if there is way to output more than 16 colours in graphics.h? I am using Ubuntu 12.04, and currently I can only output 16 colours. I have been trying to find a way to do it, but have not been able to do so. I feel it has something to do with the parameters passed to the initgraph function. I would like to be able to draw 8 bit and even 24 or even 32 bit per pixel bitmaps in graphics.h in C++ in Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: What is `graphics.h`? Did you create it yourself? I use linux mint and draw my own bitmaps using `X11`.

Comment: It is an old Borland library from the DOS days.  It's like a virus, can't get rid of the damn thing because it keeps mutating and multiplying.  Like any strong virus, it easily survives because it is so compatible with its host.  Standard PC hardware and BIOS still supports these 4-bit color modes.  Also its weakness, its gene will never be longer than 16 base-pairs.